Bitbucket Trigger-Pipeline is throwing Docker EndPoint Error
I am trying to trigger a pipeline in a different repository (within same workspace).
This step fails, even if it is the only step that I run, and I get this same error.
I'm following the steps in their documentation here https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/trigger-pipeline/src/master/
This is my bitbucket YAML
      - step:
          name: Run Tests
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/trigger-pipeline:5.8.0
              variables:
                BITBUCKET_ACCESS_TOKEN: $BITBUCKET_ACCESS_TOKEN
                REPOSITORY: 'AppQuality'
                REF_TYPE: 'branch'
                REF_NAME: 'main'
                ACCOUNT: 'REMOVED'
                WAIT: 'true'

This is the error I receive
bitbucketpipelines/trigger-pipeline:5.8.0
unable to resolve docker endpoint: open /root/.docker/ca.pem: no such file or directory
Searching for files matching artifact pattern .bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/**

I can't seem to find any reference to any similar error while Googling. I have tried changing the capitalization of the Repository, added branch reference to ensure it was trying the correct branch. I'm really at a loss here. Thank you for any help you can provide.
